# GET and POST request at the same time in NODE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a search page and I need to send an array which tell me that what is user looking for like:
{ Model: 'Jeans', Color: 'BLUE}

and I should have a GET request to receive data from database.

Can I have both Get and post request at the same time?
Do you suggest to have one function for both or one function for each? if latter then How can I pass data between functions in Express.js?

```
 app.route('/alls/:issuename')
    .get(alls.list)
    .post(alls.list2);
```

Controller

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {
    mongoose.model(var1).find({ color: var2 }).exec(function(err, alls){
        res.jsonp(alls);
    }); 
};

exports.list2 = function(req, res) {

    var var1 = req.body.Model;
    var var2 = req.body.Color;

};
```

This is ow I pass a parameter to GET in $Resource

```
angular.module('alls').factory('Alls', ['$resource', function($resource) {

return $resource('alls/:issuename', {issuename: '@issuename'},
    {   
        get:{ method: 'GET', isArray:true }

    });
}]);
```

How Can I pass an Array?

Comment: you should use a get only

Comment: How can I pass that array to GET?

Comment: you should search around on query strings. if you look at your adress bar you may notice stuff like www.someweb.com?variable1=val1&foo=bar

Comment: I edited my question with resource section and how I pass parameter to GET
How can I pass an array inside resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this

$Resource

```
angular.module('alls').factory('Alls', ['$resource', function($resource) {

return $resource('alls/:issuename', {issuename: '@issuename'},
    {

        get:{ method: 'GET',
        query: {
            Model: '',
            Color: ''
        }, isArray:true }

    });
}]);
```

And then I receive this data in my Controller

```
 exports.list = function(req, res) {

    var var1 = req.query.Model;
    var var2 = req.query.Color;

    mongoose.model(var1).find({ color: var2 }).exec(function(err, alls) {
        res.jsonp(alls);
    });



};
```

Note: Array name in $resource can be query or anything else BUT you can only receive the passed data by **req.query** in controller.

In route Section I just need get and post is redundant

Hope it Helps Someone Else!

Answer (score 0):

http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html

There is a special routing method `app.all()` which is not derived from any HTTP method. It is used for loading middleware at a path for all request methods.

In the following example, the handler will be executed for requests to “/secret” whether using GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, or any other HTTP request method supported in the [http module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_methods).

```
app.all('/secret', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Accessing the secret section ...');
  next(); // pass control to the next handler
});
```